# Component's props return null when called upon in child

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two components, CartOverview and CartCheckout. CartOverview is CartCheckout's parent.

I'm passing an array to the child component like so:

```
<cart-checkout :items="items"></cart-checkout>
```

And in the child component, I've declared the props:

```
props:['items']
```

Whenever I try to access the prop, nothing is returned. I've used Vue DevTools to look at what's going on, and the confusing part is that [I can quite clearly see that the data is being passed down correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCTwL.png)

When the parent is mounted, the items array is filled like so:

```
fetchCartItems() {
        axios.get('/cart-items')
        .then((response) => {
          this.items = response.data;
          this.total = this.getCartTotal();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      },
```

To clarify, I have been trying to get the data from the prop like so:

```
this.items
```

But like I said, [nothing is returned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt709.png)

```
getCartTotalRaw() {
        let total = 0;
        alert(this.items);
        this.items.forEach(function(item) {
          total += (Number(item.product.price) * item.quantity);
        });
        return total;
      }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: is `getCartTotalRaw` a computed function, or a normal method?

Comment: Your posted part seems ok. So can you post more code or did you use a tool like Vue Devtool to trace the data and props?

Comment: @Ferrybig a normal method.

Comment: @obfish this is the only relevant code I can think of. I've seen using the Vue Devtools that the data is being registered in the prop itself, but it's just accessing the prop that's causing a problem.

Comment: A totally blank alert may mean this.items=[]. Is the initial value of this.items = [] ?

Comment: Could be an issue with the promise itself. You're passing data from a promise to the parent which passes it to the child. However, the promise could be fulfilled after the child is mounted giving the child uninitialized data.

Comment: @obfish the initial value of items (in the parent) is in fact []. It's clear from this screenshot ( [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCTwL.png) ) that the correct data is being passed, though.

Comment: @WildBeard how would that explain [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCTwL.png)?

Comment: @Josh by the time you look at the devtools the promise has already completed and passed the data to the child.

Comment: @Josh are you attempting to use `getCartTotalRaw` when the child is mounted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As WildBeard pointed out, the promise was probably being fulfilled **after** the child was mounted. Not sure if it's the best way to go about it, but my solution was to check the length of the items array before initialising the component. Whilst this wouldn't be ideal in every circumstance as an empty array would mean the child component is never rendered, that works for my scenario as if the array is empty - the user shouldn't be seeing the button included in the child component anyway.

```
<cart-checkout v-if="items.length != 0" :items="items"></cart-checkout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> When the parent is mounted, the items array is filled like so...

You're at wrong step. You need to use `created` lifecycle hook instead. `mounted` hook is used to manipulate the data that is created or say DOM is rendered and you want to change/manipulate them.

Since there's no data till the instance is created, there will be no chance to manipulate them with mounted.

Thus, call your method inside the created() hook.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell the issue stems from your promise in the parent. While Vue is reactive by nature when the child is mounted and rendered the child doesn't yet have the `items` passed to it due to the promise.

What you can do though is add a watcher on the child. See [this example.](https://jsfiddle.net/Loncxszc/)

```
...    
watch: {
    items() {
        this.calcTotal();
    }
},
...
```

It isn't a perfect recreation, I've used `setTimeout` in place of an ajax call, but the concept is still the same. If you remove the watcher on `items` total remains 0 as it is being calculated when `mounted` is fired. The list, though, renders as normal due to the Vue's reactive nature.